# how to run two functions at the same time using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so basically what i want to do is that when i click the first button the program will keep printing hello world every one second until the second button is clicked.

here's what i did:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import tkinter as tk

call=""
def on_click1():
    while call!="stop":
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(1)

def on_click2():
    call="stop"

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("test")
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        btn1=tk.Button(root,text="button1",command=on_click1)
        btn2=tk.Button(root,text="button1",command=on_click2)
        btn1.pack()
        btn2.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

but what happens is that when i click the first button the tkinter window/gui freezes and won't let me click the second window

Comment: first thing is that `call` is not global meaning You will change those variables locally in the function, also it doesn't seem that You would in any way separate those functions, they still are running in the same thread or sth, either how I think that such a function as `print` can easily be handled using `.after()` loops

Comment: Try searching SO for `tkinter`, `sleep` and `after`.  There are many answers to this question.

Comment: what does SO mean?

Comment: Stackoverflow,  sleep stops the tkinter mainloop running.

Comment: There must be dozens upon dozens of questions about displaying a timer or clock on this site.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not preferred to use while loops with sleep function, instead use `.after()` function in tkinter.

```
import concurrent.futures
import tkinter as tk

def on_click1():
    global call                         #if not global, then this call variable will be treated as local
    print("hello")
    call = root.after(1000, on_click1)     #every 1s on_click1 function is called

def on_click2():
    global call                         #if not global, then this call variable will be treated as local
    if call is not None:
        root.after_cancel(call)         #cancels the ongoing root.after() if it exists
        call = None

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("test")
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        btn1=tk.Button(root,text="button1",command=on_click1)
        btn2=tk.Button(root,text="button2",command=on_click2)
        btn1.pack()
        btn2.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how do i restart the hello loop after i clicked the second button?

Comment: Edited my code with a solution to your problem